# Django admin list_display reverse to parent

Tags: django

I have 2 models:

1: KW (individual keywords)

2: Project (many keywords can belong to many different projects)

```
class KW(models.Model):
    ...
    project = models.ManyToManyField('KWproject', blank=True)

class KWproject(models.Model):
    ProjectKW = models.CharField('Main Keyword', max_length=1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
```

Now when user is in Admin for **KWproject** they should be able to see all keywords belonging to selected project in list_display. I achieved this but it doesn't feel like proper way.

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProjectForm
    list_display = ('Keywordd', 'author')

    def Keywordd(self, obj):
        return '<a href="url.co/admin/keywords/kw/?project__id__exact=%s&o=2&q=">%s</a>' % (obj.id, obj.ProjectKW)
    Keywordd.allow_tags = True
    Keywordd.admin_order_field = 'ProjectKW'
    Keywordd.short_description = 'ProjectKW'
```

Is there better way to link and then **list_display** all items that have reverse relationship to the model? (via "project" field in my example)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Django Admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> ManyToManyField fields aren’t supported, because that would entail
>   executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you
>   want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add
>   that method’s name to list_display. (See below for more on custom
>   methods in list_display.)

So, you may opt to implement a custom model method like so:

```
# models.py
class KW(models.Model):
    ...
    project = models.ManyToManyField('KWproject', blank=True)

class KWproject(models.Model):
    ProjectKW = models.CharField('Main Keyword', max_length=1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)

    def all_keywords(self):
        # Retrieve your keywords
        # KW_set here is the default related name. You can set that in your model definitions.
        keywords = self.KW_set.values_list('desired_fieldname', flat=True)
        # Do some transformation here
        desired_output = ','.join(keywords)
        # Return value (in example, csv of keywords)
        return desired_output
```

And then, add that model method to your list_display tuple in your ModelAdmin.

```
# admin.py
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProjectForm
    list_display = ('Keywordd', 'author', 'all_keywords')

    def Keywordd(self, obj):
        return '<a href="url.co/admin/keywords/kw/?project__id__exact=%s&o=2&q=">%s</a>' % (obj.id, obj.ProjectKW)
    Keywordd.allow_tags = True
    Keywordd.admin_order_field = 'ProjectKW'
    Keywordd.short_description = 'ProjectKW'
```

Do take note: This can potentially be a VERY EXPENSIVE operation. If you are showing 200 rows in the list, then a request to the page will execute 200 additional SQL queries.